# Azure Machine Learning - Error producing the visualization of the output

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I've recently created new experiment and set "Azure SQL Database" as data source. I've typed all necessary information to connect to database and I've run the experiment. Everything seems to be correct, but when I try to "Visualise" my data, some prompt at the bottom of the screen says:

> Error producing the visualization of the output

And that's all. As well when I click "Visualise", a window appears with empty table (column names are correct, so it's sign that it's connected to database, because it had to get names of columns from db).

Where should I look for some additional information about why it doesn't work? What do you think could cause a problem? How to fix it?

**EDIT:
More info:**

What I've already done is creating blank experiment and drag&drop "Reader" from "Data Input and Output". In "Reader" I've set "Data source" to "Azure SQL Database" and I've put login credentials. Database query: "SELECT * FROM Words" (Words is one of db tables).

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't see experiment details and how it flows, let's start from the basics. 
1. Ensure your data reader is correct and you have a query in it. I simply did select * from someschema.mytablename.
2. Route your output to a Convert to CSV.
 
3. Run your experiment and right click on the Convert task and download your dataset.

If you have data at this point the issue is elsewhere in your experiment. If you post more details about the experiment after trying this, I'd be happy to help :)

[image]

Comment: So, I downloaded this CSV, Excel told something about wrong format, but basically all required data is present. How it flows? What I've already done is creating blank experiment and drag&drop "Reader" from "Data Input and Output". In "Reader" I've set "Data source" to "Azure SQL Database" and I've put login credentials. Database query: "SELECT * FROM Words" (Words is one of db tables). What else do you need to know?

Comment: So your data is there. What happens next? What are you trying to see? What does the experiment do. Do you have any transformation tasks do you have any r tasks etc

Comment: This is just a test. I was simply trying to check if I can use data from my Azure database. I hoped to see all this data in the table. If data is actually there, why can't i see that? And why I see this error?

Comment: I can't tell you without seeing the data - can you share? I can try an experiment (email adamt at microsoft). I can first try with just the dataset if you want to send that. I have no problem visualizing my data so curious what is in your data.

Comment: I'm afraid, I can't. This would require me to send you my login credentials :/

Comment: No it wouldn't, download your csv snd send it :) or try visualizing that after reloading it under datasets and then dragging that data reader into a new experiment

Comment: I've tried splitting it in two parts and.. it works. The (much) smaller one works (here is what it contains: http://imgur.com/xCzBMQd) the bigger one still doesn't. So might it be size of my dataset?

Comment: I recall hearing some viz features won't work after 64k rows but it wouldn't fail jusy not show,  let me check .